# undefined local variable or method `f' when using hidden_field tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm following a tutorial, and i get this error when i try to add  `f.hidden_field` tag in my form.

> undefined local variable or method 'f'

```
<h1>Signing up for "<%= @subscription.plan.name %>"</h1>

<%= f.hidden_field :paypal_customer_token %>
<%= f.hidden_field :paypal_payment_token %>

<% if @subscription.paypal_payment_token.present? %>
  <H1>Payment has been provided </H1>
<% else %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= radio_button_tag :pay_with, :paypal %>
    <%= label_tag :pay_with_paypal do %>
      <%= image_tag "paypal.png" %>
    <% end %>
    <%= link_to "paypal.png", paypal_checkout_path(:plan_id => @subscription.plan_id) %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either that tutorial is broken or you missed the line where they do something like this:

```
<%= form_for @subscription do |f| %>
```